# Jquery/Javascript clone replace ID dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, clone

I have this sample content which is cloned, having id's to be replaced.

```
<div id="tabs-1"><div class="ui-widget"> 
    <label for="tags">Wohnort: </label> <input class="tags" id="tags-1" name="tags[]" type="text"/>
</div>
    <input type="hidden" class="hid_id" id="hid_id-1" name="hid_id[]"/><input type="hidden" id="hid_id2-1" class="hid_id2" name="hid_id2[]"/>
<div class="ui-widget"> 
    <label for="jahr">Geburtstag: </label> <input type="text" id="jahr-1" class="jahr dated" name="jahr[]" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$" class="dated"/>
</div></div>
```

The regex for getting the id's could be

```
 /id="[^"]+-[^"]+"/g
```

checkable here: https://regexr.com/
the matching array are
id="tags-1", id="hid_id-1", etc.
now i want those to be changed to
id="tags-2", id="hid_id-2", etc.

so i can not just replace statically but shall use the matching array Each, split and reuse the first part with adding the new id thereafter.

my code so far gets the id like this:
(the var new_id gets the id increased beforehand)

```
jQuery('#tabs-1').children().clone()
.html(function(i, oldHTML) {
var old_base = oldHTML.split("-");
var new_result = old_base[0]+"-"+ new_ide;
alert(new_result);
var new_html = oldHTML.replace(/id="[^"]+-[^"]+"/g, new_result);
})
.appendTo("#tabs-"+new_id);
```

when i would have the matches in an array i could go like:

```
arr.forEach(myFunction);
myFunction(item, index, arr){
new_var = item.split("-");
new_full_id = new_var[0] +"-"+new_full_id;
}
```

how can i get this combined to do what's intended? - Thanks so much

Comment: So you always want to increment the last number in the id, is that correct?

Comment: Giving `id` attributes a sequential number is not best practice. Skip those `id` attributes and work with indexing (in JS code and/or in CSS selectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so first of all, this solution will work correctly. But it is definitely not a fool-proof solution; nor is it the best for readability. Ideally, you should parse it as nested HTMLElements and replace each id in your format. Still, here's the solution:

---

```
/(?<= id=["'])[^"]+-(\d+)(?=["'])/g
```

As you can see [using this link](https://regexr.com/79bl0). For every match, extract the last number, increment it, and add it back. Here's how the code would look.

```js
let input = `<div id="tabs-1" data-something-id="smth-1"><div class="ui-widget"> 
    <label for="tags">Wohnort: </label> <input class="tags" id="tags-1" name="tags[]" type="text"/>
</div>
    <input type="hidden" class="hid_id" id="hid_id-1" name="hid_id[]"/><input type="hidden" id="hid_id2-1" class="hid_id2" name="hid_id2[]"/>
<div class="ui-widget"> 
    <label for="jahr">Geburtstag: </label> <input type="text" id="jahr-1" class="jahr dated" name="jahr[]" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$" class="dated"/>
</div></div>
`
let regex = /(?<= id=["'])[^"]+-(\d+)(?=["'])/g
console.log(input.replaceAll(regex, function(match) {
  let sep = match.split("-")
  let first = sep[0]
  for(let i = 1; i < sep.length-1; ++i) first += "-" + sep[i];
  return first + "-" + (parseInt(sep[sep.length-1])+1)
}))
```

PS: This will work in most modern browsers, but to be safe you should check out this link: [caniuse.com - Regex Lookbehind](https://caniuse.com/?search=regex%20lookbehind)

Comment: Hi @Robo Mop, thanks for that solution. I had to recognise your emphasizing "Ideally, you should parse it as nested HTMLElements and replace each id in your format". So do you mean it would go with $(".tags").attr("id).??? or would it be to get all ids with one function and if so, how would you process that? i also have access to the html src so therefore i could easily add classes to each id element we need to catch. Thanks for a hint in what seems a better solution.

Comment: End solution although i give credit to your answer: `code`var new_cont = jQuery('#tabs-1').clone(true).attr('id', "tabs-"+ counta);
  new_cont.find('.clon').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('id', $this.attr('id').replace(/-(\d+)/g, "-"+ counta));})`code`

Comment: Ahh sorry, I didn't see your comments. Yeah ideally I'd use plain ol' JavaScript to parse the entire input as an HTMLELement with something like `containingDiv.innerHTML = inputString`, and then recursively modifying the attributes. But yeah, your solution is equally correct.